# Firestore resoure.data.lastUpdate Rule Not Working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following rules set within my firestore, however, whenever I call the function that updates this doc, I get permission denied (FirebaseError: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.).

My goal is to allow users to update the doc every 8 hours.

```
function notThrottled() {
    return resource == null
    || request.time >= resource.data.lastUpdate + duration.value(1, "m");
}
match /security/{userId} {
    allow read, create;
    allow update, write: if notThrottled();
}
```

Am I missing something or is my code incorrect?

If I remove the notThrottled condition, I can successfully update the doc, therefore something within the function isn't working.

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to perform the update.